How to properly set up OpenLayers with Next.js?
I am trying to display a simple OpenLayers map on a new Next.js project.
The problem is that it shows me 2 maps, and they work buggy and slowly.
This is the project structure:
app/
 |__map/
 |    |__page.tsx
 |
components/
 |__MapComponent.tsx

This is the code in MapComponent.tsx:
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MapComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '300px', width: '100%' }} id="map" className="map-container" />
  );
}

export default MapComponent;

And this is in map.tsx:
'use client'
import MapComponent from "@/components/MapComponent";
export default function Page() {
    return <MapComponent></MapComponent>
}

And this is package.json:
  "name": "nextjs-ol",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.7",
    "ol": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.7",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

It results in 2 maps instead of 1 (how?) that are not working well (as if I would just install an OpenLayers project)
The reason I used useEffect is because I followed this guide: https://mxd.codes/articles/how-to-create-a-web-map-with-open-layers-and-react
But modified the code to match my versions.

As the author of rlayers, a set of React components for OpenLayers, I can assure you that using OpenLayers with React and Next.js is not exactly trivial as you will have to reimplement the React component lifecycle management.
In your case the problem is that useEffect does not delete the previously created map. By default, in developer mode, React always initializes your component twice, so that errors such as yours can easily be detected before the production build. The production build does not do this.
useEffect can return a function that will be used to unmount your component. But you will have other problems too.
